# mongoDB update unset multiple object item within array

Tags: mongodb

i want to unset multiple object within array .. this is my db data

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5440e390fb038d3062000001"),
   "firstname" : "demo2",
   "contacts" : [
      {
        "contactId" : "544372d5f9ae85d0589d2b71",
        "displayname" : "demo1",
        "accounts" : {
            "00e12ed769eb19239e218355cbe3c24f" : {
                "type" : "mobile",
                "userId" : "123456789",
                "status" : 0,
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "contactId" : "544372e4f9ae85d0589d2b72",
        "displayname" : "demo2",
        "accounts" : {
            "00e12ed769eb19239e218355cbe3c24f" : {
                "type" : "mobile",
                "userId" : "123456789",
                "status" : 0,
            }
        }
    }
 ],
}
```

i used this db query but its updating only one record

```
   db.users.update({'contacts.accounts.00e12ed769eb19239e218355cbe3c24f.userId':'123456789'},   
        {$unset:{'contacts.$.accounts.00e12ed769eb19239e218355cbe3c24f':''}},{multi:true})
```

Its updating only one  but i want to update multiple items...

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your update statements in while like:

```
while (db.users.update({
    'contacts.accounts.00e12ed769eb19239e218355cbe3c24f.userId' : '123456789'
}, {
    $unset : {
        'contacts.$.accounts.00e12ed769eb19239e218355cbe3c24f' : ''
    }
}, {
    multi : true
}).nMidified);
```

Comment: this will work with mongodb terminal but will this work in node.js with monk ?

Comment: @balaphp, I'm not sure. I didn't get this requirement from your question. You'd better check the API of monk accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.find({'contacts.accounts.00e12ed769eb19239e218355cbe3c24f.userId':'123456789'}).forEach(function(item)
    {
        var contacts = item.contacts;
        for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
        {
            var contact = contacts[i];
            delete contact.accounts['00e12ed769eb19239e218355cbe3c24f'];
        }

        // db.users.save(item);
        // use update() instead of save(
        db.users.update({'contacts.accounts.00e12ed769eb19239e218355cbe3c24f.userId':'123456789'}, item); 
    })
```

Comment: it's not true, that You can't do that. Please check documentantion and API before You state that something is impossible.

Comment: not doing it in one atomic inline operation -as You stated.

Comment: I didn't said atomic, I said you cant update multi nested array in one update query. My way is atomic, because it uses just one save() operation

Comment: You're double wrong. First of all - Your operation is not atomic. You do first find, then update. Things can change between find and update and race codition is a valid problem. Second - it is possible to update mutli nested array in one update query, as You can see in my answer. EDIT: sorry. You didnt say "atomic", but it doesnt change a thing.

Comment: @Jarema why did u delete your answer?

Comment: Because You were right about it being irrelevant, so i see no reason to leave it there. Still - Your answer is not atomic and it may override other request that updates in any way that array. Very dangerous in any production enviroment. I'll try to find better solution later today. for now - un-downvote.  Please be more careful with "can't", "it is atomic" and similar statemets thought (same applies to me) :).

Comment: @Jarema is right. It's not atomic. When do the update operation, another thread may just have modified the document. That means update might update a new document which is different to that one found from **find()**. Of course, if you just run on a single thread, it is safe.